# how is it combination prob

Tags: combinatorics

Question:Find the number of arrangements of all the letters in TALLAHASSEE. How many of these arrangements have no adjacent A's?
I want to know why it is a combination prob and not permutation.

Comment: This is a question of stars and bars. Would you want to do some research? It is not permutation unless the three a's are different.

Comment: It is a permutation problem. Anyway, what are your thoughts about the problem?

Comment: How is it a permutation problem? Combination does not matter on the order of selection, which in this case is the A's. So, shouldn't it be a combination problem?

Comment: On second thought, it is also partly  a permutation problem. The other letters can be changed. Sorry, gar.

Comment: No problem. By the way, such problems are relatively tougher, if not seen before.

Answer (score 1):

It is a **Combinatoric** problem.

As per this site's keyword tags, Combinatorics is the "study of finite, or countable, discrete structures — specifically how to count or enumerate elements in a set (perhaps of all possibilities) or any subset. It includes questions on *permutations*, *combinations*, bijective proofs, and generating functions. Combinatorics is a 'parent' of probability in that a probability is the proportion of desired outcomes out of total outcomes."

This particular problem is solved by both permutations and selections.

There are $\dfrac{8!}{1!2!1!2!2!}$ ways to permutate the symbols: "TLLHSSEE", which is a multinomial permutation.

There are 9 spaces before, between, and after each letter into which we can inject the three "A" symbols, such that no two are together.  This is a selection problem: ${9\choose 3}=\dfrac{9!}{3!6!}$

The final solution combines the two tasks: $$\frac{8!9!}{2!2!2!3!6!}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us first assume that all letters (not including the a's) are different.
Between each of them will be a space. We have a choice on where we want to put the 3 a's. We have 8 letters (not including a's), thus 9 spaces. (Don't forget the start and end) We have to choose which spaces to put an 'a' in. We will use the choose function.
The answer will be 9C3=$9*8*7/3*2*1$=84
However, do not forget that the other letters are actually different! Therefore, we have to multiply 84 with $8!/2!*2!*2!=7!$
Multiplying them together, we get 423360.

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore the fact that there is repetition of letters, you have 11! arrangements. Now, you need to consider how many of those are equal. Consider the case of $L$: there are $11C2$ spaces for the two $L$ s any arrangement of the remaining letters gives you the same word. And the same goes for the other repeated letters.

You can also use the multinomial theorem /multinomial coefficient , or you can do an inclusion-exclusion argument.