# How many words can be made using the letters from TALLAHASSEE?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

This question has already been answered ([how is it combination prob](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800079/how-is-it-combination-prob), [Trouble in finding number of permutations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73626/trouble-in-finding-number-of-permutations), [Trouble in finding number of permutations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73626/trouble-in-finding-number-of-permutations/)), I first seen it in my discrete maths book, and I understood it.

But, since this is a really difficult topic (combinatorics) for me, I was watching this [video](https://youtu.be/kWPj-Q5e9Lo) and the same problem came up but they changed it a little bit.

> Given the word TALLAHASSEE, how many arrangaments can be made **with no consecutive vowels?**

He kinda uses the same approach as the book, but the last thing he does is to order the case of $AAAEE$, which is obviously $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$. But this doesn't make sense to me at all, the problem says that you can't have **any** conscutive vowels, so he's counting them by doing that?

For me, the correct answer would be $\frac{6!}{2!2!}{7\choose 5}$, where $\frac{6!}{2!2!}$ is the number of arrangements with no $A's$ and no $E's$ and ${7\choose 5}$ are the positions where the vowels could be in between the rest of the letters.

Can someone explain this to me a little bit?

Comment: In the original post you cite, all arrangements of the A's are equivalent (that is, all the symbols are the same). Here, though, putting AAAEE into five distinct holes gives a different word that putting EEAAA into those same holes (in order).

Comment: @rogerl but when you do $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$ and then you multiply it by the rest of the things, aren't you counting the cases where for example, two $A's$ could be together? Or $AE's$, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original post you cite, all arrangements of the A's are equivalent (that is, all the symbols are the same). Here, though, putting AAAEE into five distinct holes gives a different word that putting EEAAA into those same holes (in order).

To think about it a different way, suppose all the vowels were some symbol, say $*$. Then the number of arrangements with no $*$'s together would be, as you computed, $\frac{6!}{2!2!}\binom{7}{5}$. Now you have five $*$'s that you need to replace with three $A$s and two $E$s. In how many ways can you do this? Well, you just need to choose the locations for the $A$s, which can be done in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways.

Comment: Oooo I got it now! Thank you soooo much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should break it into three separate steps like it was done in the video.

1) Number of ways to arrange $TLLHSS$: 
$$\frac{6!}{2!2!}$$ 
2) Number of ways to arrange five vowels into $7$ positions in $\_\_ \ T\_\_ \ L\_\_ \ L\_\_ \ H\_\_ \ S\_\_ \ S\_\_ \ $ one by one:
$${7\choose 5}$$
Note that here we are only interested in whether we should place a vowel in a specific position or not. In other words, we are just marking the positions for vowels (not specifying them yet). For example, one arrangement is 
$$\_\_ \ T \ V_1 \ L \ V_2 \ L \ V_3 H \ \_\_ \ S \ V_4 \ S \ V_5,$$ 
where $V_i$ is a vowel.

3) Number of ways to arrange $AAAEE$:
$$\frac{5!}{3!2!}$$
Note that for any five positions we want to place $5$ vowels in 2) there are $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$ arrangements to place $AAAEE$. It implies 
$$\_\_ \ T\color{red}AL\color{blue}AL\color{green}AH \ \_\_ \ S\color{red}ES\color{blue}E$$ and $$\_\_ \ T\color{blue}AL\color{red}AL\color{green}AH \ \_\_ \ S\color{red}ES\color{blue}E$$ and all other arrangements of $AAAEE$ in this order and in the same positions are the same arrangement.

That is it.

I have watched many videos of TheTrevTutor and must admit it is a great resource!